# Angular - OpenApi CodeGen - How to add Header in a api request?

Tags: angular, http-headers, openapi, request-headers, openapi-generator

I'm working with Angular 10. I'm using openapi codegen (auto-generated) services.

**Issue**: I want to pass `Authorization: Token 123456` in my header but can't seem to get my head around how and where exactly to add the interceptor.

My Component File is:

```
 constructor(        
    private meApi : MeService
    )


 meDetails;
  meCheck(){
      this.meApi.meRead().subscribe(
        (data: any) => {
          this.meDetails= data;
        },
        (err) => { console.error(err); },
        () => { }
      )
    }
```

Upon running this function in ngOnInIt. I get the following error:

```
401 (Unauthorized)
```

Because obviously, the authorization token is not passed with the API.

meRead() function from the auto generated service file has the following relevant code:

```
 /**
     * @param observe set whether or not to return the data Observable as the body, response or events. defaults to returning the body.
     * @param reportProgress flag to report request and response progress.
     */
    public meRead(observe?: 'body', reportProgress?: boolean, options?: {httpHeaderAccept?: 'application/json'}): Observable<User>;
    public meRead(observe?: 'response', reportProgress?: boolean, options?: {httpHeaderAccept?: 'application/json'}): Observable<HttpResponse<User>>;
    public meRead(observe?: 'events', reportProgress?: boolean, options?: {httpHeaderAccept?: 'application/json'}): Observable<HttpEvent<User>>;
    public meRead(observe: any = 'body', reportProgress: boolean = false, options?: {httpHeaderAccept?: 'application/json'}): Observable<any> {

        let headers = this.defaultHeaders;

        // authentication (DRF Token) required
        if (this.configuration.apiKeys) {
            const key: string | undefined = this.configuration.apiKeys["DRF Token"] || this.configuration.apiKeys["Authorization"];
            if (key) {
                headers = headers.set('Authorization', key);
            }
        }

        let httpHeaderAcceptSelected: string | undefined = options && options.httpHeaderAccept;
        if (httpHeaderAcceptSelected === undefined) {
            // to determine the Accept header
            const httpHeaderAccepts: string[] = [
                'application/json'
            ];
            httpHeaderAcceptSelected = this.configuration.selectHeaderAccept(httpHeaderAccepts);
        }
        if (httpHeaderAcceptSelected !== undefined) {
            headers = headers.set('Accept', httpHeaderAcceptSelected);
        }
```

How can I pass the Authorization: Token 12345 in the headers of this request?

**Summary**: How to pass Authorization header in openapi codegen service file?

Will really appreciate if you could give a detailed answer. Thank You.

Comment: Does the `key` value in the code include the `Token` prefix?

Comment: I can't find any token prefix in the service. 
I've added the entire service code here (Incase you want to have a look):
https://codeshare.io/5eEK19

Answer (score 1):

on app.modules

```
    import { environment } from './environments/environment'
```

something like

```
    const configurationFactory = () => {
        const configParams: ConfigurationParameters = {
            credentials : {
                apiKeys : environment.apiKeys["DRF Token"] ,
            }
        }
        return new Configuration(configParams)
    }
```

and on same file on imports

```
    ApiModule.forRoot(configurationFactory)
```

your environment file should follow that
so you have to add those there something like:

```
    export const environment = {
        apiKeys : {
           "DRF Token" : 'yourkey',
           "Authorization" : 'yourauth'
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass headers by altering the defaultHeaders property of the generated client, or also by providing some configuration in the ad-hoc property.
See this [blog post](https://reflectoring.io/spring-boot-springdoc/) for some other options.

```
/**
 * OpenAPI definition [...]
 */
import { ...}


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserControllerService {

    protected basePath = 'http://localhost:8081';
    public defaultHeaders = new HttpHeaders(); // <- here
    public configuration = new Configuration(); // <- or there
    public encoder: HttpParameterCodec;
    
    {...}
}
```

As for passing something useful through the {httpHeaders: '*/*'} of the method call, didn't understood how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how to pas header to the generated client.

But there is a better way to set Authorization header for each request. What you need is an HttpInterceptor.

```js
@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private tokenService: TokenService) {}

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return fromPromise(this.getToken(req, next));
  }

  async getToken(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Promise<any> {
    const authToken = this.tokenService.token;
    const authReq = req.clone({ setHeaders: { Authorization: `Bearer ${authToken}` } });
    return next.handle(authReq).toPromise();
  }
}
```

TokenService used to get the token. It depends on you how it is implemented. You need only inject it in the HttpInterceptor and get the token.